# Rails grab template file as string variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I'm creating a custom ActionMailer which will also send **Direct Messages** on **Twitter**, and **Text Message** through **Twilio**.  I need each to receive a parameter of the body of the message.  I need to use the current template as a string variable.

For example:

```
# calling send_invite's mail method will load the send_invite template
def send_invite(to)
  mail(to: to) # body parameter is automatically rendered from template
end
```

Now if I modify it to send through other services:

```
def send_invite(to, option)
  if option == :email
    mail(to: to) # body parameter is automatically rendered from template
  elsif option == :twitter
    twitter.create_direct_message(to, NEED_TEMPLATE_AS_STRING_HERE)
  elsif option == :sms
    twilio.sms(to, NEED_TEMPLATE_AS_STRING_HERE)
  end
end
```

How might I grab the template for each of these service calls?  Would there be something like:

```
message(to, render layout: false)
# or
message(to, IO.read template_path_helper("template") )
# or
message(to, template_helper.to_s)
```

How might I get the template as a string for my message body in these other methods?  What's the **Rails Way** to do it?  The templates are erb files and need to be able to render the appropriate variable as they would from a render.

I need to do it this way for translations of templates to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create the template string from the controller, and send it to your mailer, like this:

```
@parsed_template = render_to_string(:partial => 'my_partial', :layout => false, :locals => {:my_object => my_value})

SomeMailer.send_invite(to, option, @parsed_template).deliver
```

Comment: That does it!  Thanks!  I can pass the text body now to any service. ^_^

Comment: For the record `render_to_string` doesn't return a `String` object, but a `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` object.  This doesn't allow `String()` or `.to_s`.  You will need to append the `.to_str` method on it to get an actual string.  Otherwise you will ge this error: **"undefined method each_byte for nilclass"**.  I found the `.to_str` solution from this Japanese link: render_to_string の罠 - サッカーカレンダー(beta)の日記 (id:scalendar / @soccer_calendar) http://d.hatena.ne.jp/scalendar/20140806/1407322110